# MSVCRT system function return code is always -1

Tags: c, windows-7, msvcrt

What can cause MSVCRT `system()` function to always return **-1** error code, even if the application is executed and exited successfully *and returning **0** as its exit code*?

Ive made tests with TDM-GCC-4.9.2 and FASM that only calls `system()` and printing the return code, and they all print **-1** so its not my dev environment.

Also `errno` is **0** after the call to `system()` and `GetLastError` returns **18** *There are no more files*, which is odd.

In fact *every* application on my system that uses `system()` now always assumes it failed.

So this is a global problem with MSVCRT that i cant seem to reproduce on any other machine, some help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: After some debugging, `system` calls `_spawnve` which in turn calls `CreateProcessA` and then `WaitForSingleObject`. After the executable terminates it calls `GetExitCodeProcess` and that is the one that returns **-1** which then gets fed back up the chain.

**EDIT 2**: After some more testing, it seems `system` only returns **-1** if the called process returns **0** otherwise it returns the correct value.

**EDIT 3**: Just to clarify, even though `system` returns **-1**, the called process is executed successfully.

**EDIT 4**: Here are my test sources.
The one that always return **0** success:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[argc]) {
    printf("success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The one that always fails:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[argc]) {
    printf("failure\n");
    return 1;
}
```

And the one that calls it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[argc]) {
    printf( "success == %d %d\n", system("test_success.exe", errno);
    printf( "failure == %d %d\n", system("test_fail.exe", errno);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
success
success == -1 0
failure
failure == 1 0
```

**EDIT 5**: Since `system` calls `_spawnve` calls `CreateProcess` i tried them all, and they all return **-1** when calling `cmd /c test_success` but when calling `cmd /c test_fail` they work as expected.
So this seems to be a deeper issue not directly related to `system`.

**EDIT 6**: After much faffing around i changed `ComSpec` to `C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_e932cc2c30fc13b0\cmd.exe` and everything works now!
Which is a bit weird since im on an *Intel Core 2 Duo*, and its probably not the right thing to do here, but still im satisfied :p

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the system() function with a debugger to see what is happening?  Also, check the value of the ComSpec environment variable, and that `cmd.exe` itself hasn't been corrupted in some way.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: COMSPEC is "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"  and calling it recursively with /c works as expected. I will try debugging it though...

Comment: did you try using <code>GetLastError()</code> and check for error code?

Comment: @GingerJack: GetLastError returns 18 "There are no more files" which just doesnt make any sense.

Comment: If it returns -1 then you are supposed to use *errno* to obtain the error code.  Do not use GetLastError().  Document the value of errno you see.

Comment: Ignore GetLastError, MSDN documents that errno is set in case of an error and it does not say anything about GetLastError. It might just be that system does not change the last error and it is the one that was set before you called system.

Comment: Please show your exact code. If it is `system("ls")` then your test is wrong, because ls does not work on Windows/cmd.exe.

Comment: @HansPassant: I already did, and its 0. There are only 4 documented error codes for system, and none of them come as far as starting the executable.

Comment: @WernerHenze: I used LS because it has a short name, and i have a win32 version that works just fine in windows and cmd.exe, LS is not the issue. But il revise the question.

Comment: Hard to guess what kind of disease your system() suffers from.  If you get a 0 for errno then there was no error.  So just ignore it, I suppose.  You *can* debug it, you've got the source of the CRT on your machine.  Compile with /MT.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yeah, im stumped too.  I have no sources as i dont have visual studio, only mingw.  I did step through it in OllyDebug though but didnt find anything that stood out.

Comment: Works here with MSVC 2010. To narrow it down I would run cmd.exe and first `test_success.exe & echo %errorlevel%` and second `cmd /c test_success.exe & echo %errorlevel%`.

Comment: @WernerHenze: When called manually in **cmd** they both work as expected, but i did some more tests using `_spawnve` and `CreateProcess and WaitForSingleObject and GetExitCodeProcess` directly and calling `cmd /c test_success` and they all fail with **-1** but `cmd /c test_fail` works. So it seems to be related to calling **cmd** for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Im adding an answer to myself because i consider this done.

Changing `ComSpec` from `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` to `C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_e932cc2c30fc13b0\cmd.exe` solved all the issues i had with bogus exit codes.

Answer (score -1):

here is what the manual for 'system()' has to say about the returned value

```
   The value returned is -1 on  error  (e.g.,  fork(2)  failed),  and  the
   return  status  of the command otherwise.  This latter return status is
   in the format specified in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the command
   will  be  WEXITSTATUS(status).   In case /bin/sh could not be executed,
   the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).

   If the value of command is NULL, system() returns nonzero if the  shell
   is available, and zero if not.

   system() does not affect the wait status of any other children.
```